# Really loud sound input on PopOS 22.04 on an old Positivo Sim+ laptop

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pulse-audio, pipewire

My laptop (Positivo Sim+) is really old, but I never complained about audio input quality when I used Linux. Some BSODs later and a miraculous fix, I got my laptop again and installed Linux on it because my previous experience with it was great.

When in an online meeting I find that my audio is really loud and makes a lot of horrible noise (like those bad YouTube videos with a horrible microphone), my built in mic isn’t professional level, but it was never that bad either.

Anyways, here is the [output of `alsa-info`](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=22337c05e8c4e65dca95e52153deed4405b96d8b) command.

Also, tried some common troubleshooting from the ArchWiki or even System76 itself but there is no file `default.pa` in `/etc/pulse/` and `daemon.conf` is empty in that directory and in the home local directory as well.

Fish didn’t detect any `pulseaudio` command exposed from PATH and when briefly looking the alsa info, only pipewire was mentioned.

**--Alternative explanation based on comments & @gregg's understanding:**

I believe OP (Original Poster) is saying the audio had been fine previously. BSOD's were from Windows when laptop was overheating from a fan obstruction & it appears someone else fixed the laptop. OP then installed [Pop!_OS (linux distro based on Ubuntu, System76 is company who made distro)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop!_OS) & noticed the problem. The problem is during an online meeting laptops built-in microphone seems to cause horrible noise (guessing [microphone feedback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_feedback)) on the internal speakers of the laptop. The horrible noise can also be heard on wired headphones. No problems playing audio files or watching youtube videos. **So the issue seems to be the laptops buil-in microphone**. Turning down the microphone or adjusting setting/filters hasn't helped. **Soundcard model: Realtek ALC269VB**

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details: What is the exact make and model of this laptop? And are the speakers external speakers? If so, what is the exact make and model of the speakers?

Comment: Could you expand and explain what is going on in that first paragraph? Where was your laptop that you got it back from? Linux does BSOD, so can you explain what's going on there?

Comment: Sorry, currently i can't tell more of my laptop because i'm not with it, but i'll be in some days. @music2myear it got bsods when i used windows, system was heating too much since the fans were obstructed. When it got fixed, i haven't testee anything (because i thought it was working) and just installed Pop Os with all the essentials working. I only saw that the audio wasn't working properly later on

Comment: Sorry, "Linux does NOT BSOD" is what I meant to say above.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 i'm currently with it rn, but i'm not a tech guy, so idk about make and model of it, but no, the speakers are internal. Where can i get the info of my machine to answer your former question?

Comment: @Giacomo1968, all i can see is the branding "Positivo Sim+" at the back, and there are no keyboard stickers besides one that says that i can watch videos and imges in 3d, i don't believe that it does have some utility, even the brand name.

Comment: 1)your title says 'sound input' yet you seem to mention audio output to built-in speakers...so is the issue the speakers or a quality issue with your microphone where other people can't hear you? 2)You say the speakers were 'never that bad', did the speakers work fine AFTER you had the repair/fix? 3)Did the speakers ever work properly in Linux? 4)If you plug in headphones do those sound OK? if so that likely means the audio system/driver/setup is fine & maybe the speakers just went bad (maybe during the repair)? 5)I'd try a linux live or UltimateBootCD to see if issue happens there

Comment: 6)Does the horrible noise happen anytime you play any audio (file, youtube video, random website)? Could be a setting or an issue specific to the meeting software/site. 7)I see you mention your 'mic' in the bounty, if you mute yourself does the bad sound go away? It's possible your audio levels are just high so you are hearing a feedback loop (sound out of speakers goes back into microphone over & over till it squeals)

Comment: @gregg my bad, microphone, so 1) yes, 2) never tested, 3) never tested also i only installed in this machine after the repair, 4) no, 5) gonna try, 6) no, 7) yes, since it is microphone loud noise, and even with low mic and lots of audio filters the noise strikes back

Comment: @RafaelplayerxdYT I think you might have better luck asking on these other SE sites: _askubuntu.com_ and/or _unix.stackexchange.com_
I'm guessing its either a audio driver and/or complex-audio-settings/adjustments-needed causing your issue. Based on what I understand it appears to be a internal 'microphone feedback' with your soundcard `Realtek ALC269VB`. I suspect a simple workaround for the time being would be a wired headset (headphones that include a microphone). This google search yielded others with similar issues: https://www.google.com/search?q=Realtek+ALC269VB+microphone+feedback